# The category of sheaves on a site that is not abelian

Tags: ct.category-theory

Is there an example that the category of sheaves of abelian groups on a site is not an abelian category?

Comment: Sheaves of what?

Comment: Abelian groups, sorry for the unclearness

Comment: The Wikipedia article on abelian categories says that all such categories are abelian.

Answer (score 2):

The category of sheaves of abelian groups on a site is always abelian. See Theorem 2.1.4 on page 20 of

- Michael Artin - *Grothendieck Topologies* (1962)

which is available online: http://www.math.ubc.ca/~gor/Artin-GT.pdf

Once you construct the sheafification functor in the context of an arbitrary site most of the basic results in the classical theory of sheaves can be carried over to the context of sites without (much) modification.

Comment: I would argue that this suggestion has the wrong flavor to it.  First, it is not true in general that there exists a sheafification functor for sheaves taking values in an arbitrary category.  This is known to fail in almost every case.  It is known, however, that there is always a sheafification for sheaves of _sets_.  Then, instead of saying that we have a sheaf of abelian groups, we really have an abelian group in the category of sheaves of sets.  We can see that the category of abelian groups in a Grothendieck topos is necessarily abelian with just a little bit more effort.

Comment: But sheafification always exists for sheaves taking values in the category of abelian groups. It seems odd to me to disregard sheafification simply because it doesn't work for arbitrarily-valued sheaves. All of the intuition from the classical theory of abelian sheaves carries over to the context of sites by thinking in this way. Other than sheaves of sets, how often do we come across sheaves with values is a non-abelian category?

Comment: @Beren: You'd be surprised what computer-scientists and logicians do with sheaves.

Comment: Although it is nice that we can think about sheaves of abelian groups as abelian group objects in the category of sheaves of sets (the Grothendieck topos Harry refers to), personally this isn't the most transparent way for me to understand why the category of abelian sheaves on a site in abelian.

Comment: I edited, because it is simply _not true_ that sheaves on an arbitrary site form an abelian category. Only sheaves of abelian groups. You may argue this is common usage in algebraic geometry, but not in category theory, and someone stumbling across this answer may get in a muddle. As to sheaves valued in other categories, what about sheaves of groupoids? Sheaves of crossed modules? Sheaves of arbitrary groups? e.g. http://arxiv.org/abs/0909.3350

Comment: @David: Thanks. The original question was about sheaves of abelian groups, so that was what I meant.

Comment: @Andrej: Computer scientists work with sheaves??  I would indeed be surprised.  (I wonder whether you mean "mathematicians working in the area of theoretical computer science"?)

Comment: People who work on concurrency models sometimes use sheaves. eg http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayAbstract?fromPage=online&aid=4439500 and http://books.google.com.au/books?id=fAJrSYIrDuQC&pg=PA81&lpg=PA81&dq=concurrency+models++sheaves.&source=bl&ots=Lpiz-Z6Bik&sig=uzD66421LznU4NdIntdwKuzONCo&hl=en&ei=9eFdTcHWJJGWvAP8taWDDg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CBkQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=concurrency%20models%20%20sheaves.&f=false